# Simple angular app - Shopping website

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular.js, e-commerce

In looking for a bit of feedback about an Angular [app](https://github.com/kevinmck91/Angular-GemStore/tree/1fa3b9ddde8b7b94b6ce762e3f34ca8dad24c75b) I have created.

I'm new to angular I want to clean up the loose ends before I carry on and add new functionality.

Below is the code snippet of *index.html* which includes custom directives that includes a block of HTML and various angular elements

It also includes a `$http` service to fetch Json from an external file

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="product.directives.js"></script>

<h1 class="text-center">{{store.title}}</h1>
<ul class="list-group container">
    <li class="list-group-item col-sm-12" ng-repeat="product in store.products ">
        <h1>
            <product-title></product-title>
        </h1>
        <img ng-src="{{product.images[0].full}}" />
        <p ng-hide="product.canPurchase">Item is not available for purchase</p>
        <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to cart</button>
        <product-panels></product-panels>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

This is my app.js which contains the controllers

```
var app = angular.module('store', ['store-products']);

app.controller("ReviewController", function () {
// New review array slot is created and assigned blank
this.review = {};

// Form triggers function to push new review slot into array
this.addReview = function (product) {
    product.reviews.push(this.review);
    // Set the review form to blank again
    this.review = {};
}
});

app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.title = "Angular App";
    console.log('test');
var store = this;
//store.products = [];

$http.get('/products.json').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    store.products = response.data;
});
}]);
```

and finally here is my directives.js. with the logic being stored in external html files.

```
var app = angular.module('store-products', []);

app.directive('productPanels', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'product-panels.html',
    controller: function () {

        this.tab = 1;

        this.selectTab = function (setTab) {
            this.tab = setTab;
        }

        this.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
            return this.tab === checkTab;
        }

    },
    controllerAs: 'panel',
};
});

app.directive('productTitle', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'product-title.html'
};
});
```

Comment: The link to [app](https://github.com/kevinmck91/Angular-GemStore/tree/1fa3b9ddde8b7b94b6ce762e3f34ca8dad24c75b)  appears to yield a 404... can you correct that?

Comment: What is in *product-panels.html*? I presume *product-title.html* mostly displays the name/title of the product.... Does [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mVFGdcybfUJJLeGJTm4?p=preview) look similar to what your code looks like? Feel free to fork it, update it and add a link so we can have more context...

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you have a spot for controllers, but then in your directive you declare a function for the Controller Attribute instead of using a controller that you have already at your disposal from the controller's section.

I would think that you would want to be able to reuse that function that controls tab selection, you should create a controller for that so that you can reuse it on several pages, rather than write from scratch every time you create a page with Panel tabs.

Comment: It is difficult to know what the *panels* contains (presumably something important for each product...). I [made a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mVFGdcybfUJJLeGJTm4?p=preview) and found that if the OP wanted the scope of each panel controller to be different, the `scope: {}` could be added to the return POJO for the directive... I also couldn't get the `selectTab()` functions to work unless I inject $scope to the controller

Comment: you should be able to inject the scope into a Controller that already exists.  simple Panel functionality should be reusable.  you should be able to call more than one controller in the Controller attribute of the return of the directive.  so any extra functionality that is above the simple Panel Functionality should be in a separate controller